# libGDX - remove color from imagebutton

Tags: android, button, colors, libgdx, imagebutton

I made an Imagebutton called skillButton and changed its color by using

```
skillButton.setColor(Color.RED);
```

It works fine, but what can I do to remove the color and get the original image (color) back? I tried Color.CLEAR which makes the complete button invisible. I also tried some rgba values, but is there no better way?

Thx and regards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard colour is `Color.WHITE`. The actual colour of the image/texture is actually multiplied by the colour you set on the button. `Color.CLEAR` is a colour with an alpha value of 0 which means 100% transparent = invisible.

`Color.WHITE` means that each colour component of the original picture is multiplied by 1 and thus will not change.

`skillButton.setColor(Color.WHITE);` will "reset" the button to its normal colors.